# Ubuntu will not boot normally after nvidia driver install

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I was trying to install the new NVIDIA drivers and now this is what I see.

[image]

Sometimes I can get to the default login screen but when I log as my user I get back to this screen.

Comment: Apparently you need to fix lines 58 and 59 from the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. Try commenting those lines out (put a `#` symbol at the beginning of the text on line 58 and on line 59, so `hi you` would become `#hi you`. You need to open the file as root, eg `sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and turn on line numbering) and see what happens. Not sure if this is the source of your problem, but maybe it will help to reveal that.

Answer (score 8):

OP's answer removed from the question (and edited to fix possible issues):

> So, I fixed the problem.
>
> First press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in with your username and password.
>
> Then you will need to remove the old driver:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get purge ^nvidia-
> ```
>
> After that you will need to add the graphics-driver PPA
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
> ```
>
> and then
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> Search for the latest Nvidia drivers for your hardware [here on the
>    Nvidia site](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html).
>
> In my case I used
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install nvidia-384
> ```
>
> And done, just reboot and you should be ready to go.

Comment: It does not work, hence wish i could downvote!

Comment: It says `ERROR: '~graphics-drivers' user or team does not exist`. What must be done to resolve this ?

Comment: @TanishqVyas try again - maybe you mistyped the command - there should not be a `~` character in it. I just tested and it worked for me

Comment: @Zanna My cross checked my command but it still gave the same error

Comment: hmmm... no idea

Answer (score 8):

TLDR: deleting `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` solved my boot issue. Continue reading to see if you had a similar issue.

I stumbled across this question when trying to solve my "Ubuntu will not boot normally after nvidia driver install" problem. It might not be the exact same problem, but the title matches and people searching for the issue I had might land here.

I have Ubuntu 18.04 with a working nvidia-driver-415. While playing around with OpenCL, Vulkan and other GPU-related stuff, I upgraded to nvidia-driver-440 (I did also try to install drivers from nvidia site as well). After that I was unable to get to the login screen when nvidia prime profile was enabled (enabling intel profile works ok).

I spent the whole day doing various things, including this one (some other articles also suggest something like this), it turned out that I had an outdated `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` which had to be deleted as suggested in this post: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-18-lts-nvidia-440-unable-to-make-nvidia-the-primary-display-driver/107632

Comment: this really solved my problem! I have been stuck in this mess for two days, and tried every solution I can found with no luck! untill I got this!!Thank you man, you really saved my life! (ubuntu20.04 + gtx 1050)

Comment: Works like a harm! I tried installing other drivers, purging, etc, but only  this solution work!

Comment: After fiddling with other changes this solved my problem. I was also playing with nvidia because it was not supporting dual monitors. Now everything is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Start Ubuntu in recovery mode.
 Choose "Drop To Root Shell Prompt'. 
By default, this will allow you to access the file system in read-
 only mode. 
 Switch to read/write mode by executing This:. 
 $ mount -o remount,rw /
Purge Nvidia by executing:. 
$ sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
$ reboot
This will get your system started.
 Then install the compatible Nvidia driver.

Comment: Doing this still shows a similar screen as shared in the question. How to proceed ?

Comment: It solved my problem

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem after installing the latest NVIDIA driver on fresh Ubuntu 20.04.

What helped me solve the problem is running after NVIDIA installation:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

To explain.
I just got a black screen on reboot after installing the NVIDIA recommended driver. Further, I used [`nomodeset` feature](https://askubuntu.com/a/38834) to enter the Ubuntu.

When in additional software I tried to switch to the old driver, I noticed it said: **Continue using a manually installed driver** and all other options greyed out. To solve that problem, I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1237598/1034078).

Afterwards the installed nvidia driver was correctly identified and after reboot, it did not get stuck at the black screen any more.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was getting a black screen after updating an nvidia driver on ubuntu 23.10, this solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem (after changed the default driver to the system-recommended Nvidia 435/440 and reboot) in Ubuntu 19.10. I have tried many solutions on internet (e.g., edit grub/nomodeset, blacklist nouveau, manual install old nvidia-driver-418), but none of them worked. Desperate and frustrated, but not gave up!

My final fix is pretty funny ... After selecting the latest nvidia driver in Ubuntu/Additional Driver, I run nvidia-smi in the terminal, which gave me an error like "Unable to communicate with GPU because it is insufficiently powered". Was it the problem? Doubted. BTW, my EVGA/RTX 2070 SUPER black has two power connectors, a 6-pin (optional as said in the manual) and an 8-pin (this was the only one I connected). Simply connecting the second port, now everything works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Enter Recovery Mode, choose "Drop To Root Shell Prompt", if you have the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` delete it (on modern Ubuntu this file is auto-managed with other ones). Reboot, and try.

If that doesn't help reenter "Root Shell Prompt" you can erase nvidia drivers and try another version. For example:

```
apt remove nvidia-driver-515 --autoremove -yqq && apt install nvidia-driver-510 -yqq
```