# Not able to change the Nvidia driver in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, 20.04

In *Additional Drivers* under Software & Updates, the NVIDIA driver is stuck on *Continue using a manually installed driver*, and all other options are greyed out.

I want to set the driver to proprietary driver(`nvidia-driver-390`), which was originally selected before I changed it to the open source driver, but now it is stuck.

How can I resolve this issue? Should  remove all NVIDIA drivers and install them again? If so , how to do it safely in Ubuntu 20.04?

Additional info:

1. `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log` output: https://termbin.com/hqo3
2. `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` output: https://termbin.com/bog0

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: The proprietary dtiver is installed now. It must be a bug in GUI.

Comment: but how can i change the driver? it is not letting me change as they are greyed out.

Comment: What do you want to change? Did you reboot?

Comment: The 390 is the only applicable driver for this card. It is installed now?

Comment: yes, i did multiple times by now, i will try once again. i want to select dfferent drivers available, as i have observed that the xorg process is using a lot of cup

Comment: What are "other drivers available"? There should be `nouveau` and `390`.

Comment: yes the 390 is installed and was selected initially, but i changed it to the open source driver, and it hanged and now it is stuck. i want to try selecting out open source and 390 again

Comment: Try to run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`.

Comment: other options are 390, 340, and open source version

Comment: ok i did autoinstall, and now it is installing a bunch of stuff related to nvidia

Comment: Reboot after it is installed and see if it is fixed.

Comment: @Pilot6 yes that did solve the issue. now the 390 is selected, and the "continue to use a manually installed driver" option is gone. i searched quite a bit about this issue and a lot of people have gotten this issue in the past, the  way they solved it involved a lot of complex steps like uninstalling  and installing. I am grad it was really this simple to solve it. i have also noticed that now it is using a lot less cpu. you should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This problem should be fixed by running

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

after a reboot.

Comment: This one works for me, but after reboot, my mouse becomes lag. It is like: I move my mouse from right to left, half seconds later, the mouse on the screen starts moving. Could anyone help please?

Comment: I'm here to report that my computer just underwent this procedure and that no mouse lag was detected after reboot. My Nvidia driver went from 450 to 460 on a GeForce 920M.

Comment: I tried doing this and I see this:                                                                                                                   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-470 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-470 (= 470.57.02-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed                                                                                   <snip>                            Recommends: libnvidia-gl-470:i386 (= 470.57.02-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: I see when running `ubuntu-drivers -h` to see the help text, the following: `autoinstall  Deprecated, please use "install" instead`. I can't say why this is, but just something to note.

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 22.04.1.

Comment: this immediately fixed my issue with my secondary monitor not working, it also seemed to pull my old configuration (left monitor is the secondary monitor). thanks.

Comment: This solved my problem (couldn't select drivers). ** NOTE **  Upon reboot the system hung up, after displaying a lot of diagnostics. I rebooted into Ubuntu recovery mode, selected fix broken packages (and authorized a remount), and when I rebooted everything was okay.

Answer (score 15):

I encountered myself in a similar situation because of broken packages (Ubuntu complained on launching `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`; further in `Software & Updates` -> `Additional Drivers` my Nvidia graphics was locked to `manual installation`). I solved it like this:

1. [Remove all nvidia packages and make sure nouveau is installed](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-uninstall-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux) (you need sudo rights):

```
dpkg -P $(dpkg -l | grep nvidia-driver | awk '{print $2}')
apt autoremove
apt install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

2. Reboot
3. Reinstall latest nvidia packages (again, sudo rights):

```
ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Comment: Awesome, I followed your guide and it worked,

Thanks,

Comment: Seems to be the current way of getting it working in Ubuntu 22.04.1 a.k.a install Noveau drivers - reboot - install new one.

Comment: I had a problem with 1024x768 resolution, and after `2.` step it started working. I will try to work on opensource drivers for now, cause nvidia drivers give me the resolution problem after almost every update.

Answer (score 5):

I also couldn't update to a newer Nvidia driver because a manual driver was installed, in my case from 470 to 510 driver on an Focal Desktop system of Canonical.

My solution was:

1. Open a terminal and run the command:

   ```
   sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
   ```

   The above will install the newest recommended driver.
2. Wait until all automatic commands are executed and reboot the system.
3. The Linux kernel loaded the 510 driver.
4. Checked *Additional Drivers* in Software & Updates, which points to Nvidia 510 driver.

The accidentally selected manual driver option was removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for the mouse lag situation. open NVIDIA Settings.

```
$ nivdia-settings
```

select this -> PRIME Profiles - NVIDIA (Performance Mode)

after reboot, your mouse or the animation of Ubuntu is as smooth as it used to be.

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced the issue of being unable to select a driver other than *Continue using a manually installed driver*.

`sudo ubuntu-drivers install nvidia-driver-525` only reported that I already have that driver installed.

What fixed the issue for me was:

1. `sudo apt purge nvidia-driver*` (followed by `sudo apt autoremove` just to be sure)
2. `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` (to have at least some driver)
3. Reboot
4. `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525` (this is the important part that differs from other guides, the rest is more or less the same)
5. Reboot

And then I could see the appropriate proprietary driver selected.