# Ubuntu 20.04 Using "Additional Drivers" Not Able To Switch To Nouveau Open-Source Driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, system-settings, nouveau

Previously in earlier Ubuntu editions I have been able to tick, during install, the proprietary codecs choice and then later after install reboot go in to **Software & Updates** app and select **Additional Drivers** then change from the nVidia driver 390 and select the open source Nouveau driver.  I select **Apply** and when that is complete, I would have the Nouveau driver.

In 20.04, when I reboot, I get a screen of gigantic sized page which won't fit on the screen and when I go back into **Software & Updates > Additional Drivers** the ticked selection is **Using Manually Installed Driver** which was never a choice.  All other options are grayed out and I am stuck in this limbo.  Why is it impossible now to select the Nouveau driver?

I have liked the Nouveau driver since it works for me, and because the screen tells me that Ubuntu can only "improve" the Nouveau driver, not the proprietary ones.  Am just trying to help out with that.

Comment: I had a similar problem. I fixed it by doing the steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237590/not-able-to-change-the-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to change the Nvidia driver in ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237590/not-able-to-change-the-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu-20-04)