# No spinner animation on boot screen (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: boot, 20.04, themes, plymouth

That's it. For some reason, my boot/shutdown screen doesn't show the spinning animation anymore.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with Bundgie.

I've tried almost everything, like:

- `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`
- `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`
- Reinstalled plymouth and all packages related to it.
- Reinstalled all plymouth themes.
- Changed between themes and tested.
- `sudo -H gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash` to insert `FRAMEBUFFER=y`

Can you guys help me out on this? Thanks in advance.

EDITED to show the results of `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` as suggested by @heynnema

```
There are 5 choices for the alternative default.plymouth (providing /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth).

  Selection    Path                                                                               Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-budgie-logo/ubuntu-budgie-logo.plymouth           150       auto mode
* 1            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/bgrt/bgrt.plymouth                                       110       manual mode
  2            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/spinner/spinner.plymouth                                 70        manual mode
  3            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-budgie-logo/ubuntu-budgie-logo-scale-2.plymouth   149       manual mode
  4            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-budgie-logo/ubuntu-budgie-logo.plymouth           150       manual mode
  5            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth                         100       manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Results of `cat /etc/default/grub`:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash net.ifnames=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE="2560x1440x16"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
#GRUB_THEME="/usr/share/grub/themes/Vimix/theme.txt"
```

Comment: I'm out of ideas, don't know what else to do.

Comment: Edit your question and show me the output of `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Here it is.

Comment: Have you tried selecting #2 from that command? Then do `sudo update-initramfs -u -k $(uname -r)` and then `reboot`.

Comment: @heynnema Yes, already tried. I've tried every single option from that list with no success.

Comment: And you did the `update-initramfs` command? And you're booting to the newest kernel? Do you see the OEM logo at boot now? Show me `cat /etc/default/grub`.

Comment: @heynnema Yes, I've always run update-initramfs after making changes for that matter. Yes, I'm booting to the newest kernel available. My OEM logo is showing on boot and if there is a job to run when I shut down or reboot my computer, the OEM logo is also shown with Ubuntu Logo, but in both cases the spinning wheel is gone.

Comment: @heynnema I've edited the post to show you the result.

Comment: Select #2 in `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`. Comment out `GRUB_GFXMODE="2560x1440x16"` in /etc/default/grub, then run `sudo update-grub`, then `reboot`.

Comment: @heynnema did everything you suggested, still no spinning wheel animation. OEM logo is showed when restarting, booting or shutdown.

Comment: Last try... with `GRUB_GFXMODE` commented out, edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash` to remove FRAMEBUFFER=y (or remove splash if that's the only thing in it). Update-initramfs. Reboot.

Comment: Your computer is in UEFI mode, yes?

Comment: Yes, it was working normal when I first installed Ubuntu 20.04. For some random reason it stopped, don't know why. EDIT: @heynnema Tried the last suggestion, still doesn't show the spinning wheel animation. I'm almost giving up.

Comment: I'm out of ideas too. Maybe somebody else will chime in. If you figure it out, please let me know.

Comment: No ideas but upvoting to draw more attention to question.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this as an answer because I don't have enough points to simply comment and this may be useful to anyone who stumbles across this question.

I had a similar issue upgrading from Xubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 21.04 (home folder has it's own partition so swapping distros shouldn't be a problem). I ran through similar steps as yourself including running `update-initramfs` but couldn't get it sorted.

Then I noticed that when I went into the 'Additional Drivers' utility, all of the options for the Nvidia proprietary driver and Nouveau were greyed out. It stated I had a manually installed driver but this shouldn't be the case because the distro was freshly installed. I had asked the distro installer to use the proprietary display drivers but presumably they should come from the repos, not as a manual install.

I followed the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237590/not-able-to-change-the-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu-20-04) to resolve the driver issue and it also fixed the issue with the missing Plymouth spinner during boot.

I believe the proprietary drivers aren't being configured correctly when they're installed at the same time as the distro and this may be causing the issues with Plymouth.