# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS no Boot Animation

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, plymouth

I facing the issue that I see no Boot Animation like the spinner and the Ubuntu Logo. Only the OEM logo (ASRock) is shown. I followed some Instructions mentioned in [No spinner animation on boot screen (Ubuntu 20.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256965/no-spinner-animation-on-boot-screen-ubuntu-20-04) but with no success.

I compared my Desktop and Notebook (where all is shown (Dell OEM Logo, Spinner and Ubuntu Logo)) in `/etc/default/grub` and `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`. Both are the same.

`/etc/default/grub`:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

`sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`:

```
Es gibt 3 Auswahlmöglichkeiten für die Alternative default.plymouth (welche /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth bereitstellen).

  Auswahl      Pfad                                                         Priorität Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/bgrt/bgrt.plymouth                 110       automatischer Modus
  1            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/bgrt/bgrt.plymouth                 110       manueller Modus
  2            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/spinner/spinner.plymouth           70        manueller Modus
  3            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth   100       manueller Modus
```

And here the Ubuntu boot record:

```
recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd1,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt2  454b3874-3032-4cb6-9e5c-92a00ed53afb
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 454b3874-3032-4cb6-9e5c-92a00ed53afb
fi
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-52-generic root=UUID=454b3874-3032-4cb6-9e5c-92a00ed53afb ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-52-generic
```

I also reinstalled all plymouth related packages and there's no success either.

The following packages are installed:

```
libplymouth4/now 0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.2 amd64  [Installiert,lokal]
libplymouth5/focal-updates,now 0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
plymouth-label/focal-updates,now 0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
plymouth-theme-spinner/focal-updates,now 0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.1 amd64  [installiert]
plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo/focal-updates,now 0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.1 amd64  [installiert]
plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text/focal-updates,now 0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
plymouth/focal-updates,now 0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
```

**Edit 2020-11-04:** It might be a issue with the proprietary Nvidia drivers as mentioned in this [link](https://www.onetransistor.eu/2016/03/plymouth-fix-nvidia.html). I followed this instructions but got no success. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362722/how-to-fix-plymouth-splash-screen-in-all-ubuntu-releases/362998#362998) the same but no success.

Btw. my Nvidia driver version is 450.80.02.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `set gfxpayload=keep` option

Like this:

```
recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
set gfxpayload=keep
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd1,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt2  454b3874-3032-4cb6-9e5c-92a00ed53afb
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 454b3874-3032-4cb6-9e5c-92a00ed53afb
fi
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-52-generic root=UUID=454b3874-3032-4cb6-9e5c-92a00ed53afb ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-52-generic
```