# Laptop overheating, can't install nvidia graphics drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, overheating

I'm fairly new to the linux world, I've installed and started TLP based on some other answers here.

One of the answers had mentioned that I should verify if my external graphics drivers have been installed, I don't think they are? I don't really know if this is some generic driver that's been installed and if it is the cause of the overheating issue.
[Here is the additional drivers tab from Software Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si8Jo.png)

As you can see all the other options are greyed out? What does this mean? Am I right to assume that Ubuntu is using a generic driver?

Comment: Already answered here -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237590/not-able-to-change-the-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu-20-04

I solved my issue by typing `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`