# Ubuntu 22.04 system freeze randomly - completely unresponsive (keys + mouse)

Tags: partitioning, freeze, 22.04, system

I bought a new computer very recently, and I installed Ubuntu 22.04. I've experienced random freezes ever since I got it.

I've tried reinstalling Ubuntu 6+ times. The freezes can even happen in the installation process if I'm slow enough. I've also tried looking at my power settings in Ubuntu and Bios but any changes I've made had not any effect. Initially I thought it happened only after inactivity (leaving the computer idle for a few minutes) but I just experienced it again, trying to write this question. The only work I did in the last 10mins the computer is on was to answer to an email.

Specs:

Model: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. X570 GAMING X
  RAM: 16GB
  CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5700g with Radeon graphics × 16
  GPU: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti

It just froze again. I've only tried writing this question since opening the computer this time. I tried <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SysReq</kbd> + <kbd>REISUB</kbd>, but it did nothing.

- Disk 1 - SSD (1TB) Reserved BIOS (1 MB), EFI (1 GB), swap (64 GB), "\" (~400 GB), "\home" (the rest)
- Disk 2 - HDD (4TB) "\hdd" (all memory)

It froze again. If it's any indicator, *maybe* it happens more often when I use Firefox, but the system *has* frozen in sessions without opening Firefox.

**New INFO:** I can replicate the problem by having a youtube video play at 1080p on Chrome browser. My computer will freeze in 5-10 mins without fail. No problems however while in a 2 hours zoom meeting by browser.

Comment: Did you install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: I had similar issues both when my RAM and SSD was dying. I would start by removing all but one RAM stick and try if it's freezing again. You can also try to SSH into your machine when it freezes and check `htop` or `top` for processes running wild in case it's a software problem

Comment: I just installed Nvidia drivers, I had the same problem as this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237590/not-able-to-change-the-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu-20-04 I will be on the lookout for any problems and if it freezes again I will write a new comment

Comment: @Pilot6 It froze again, the moment I opened Firefox... It can't be the browser's fault, can it?

Comment: experience the same - just slowing down to zero. cpu usage is <2%

Comment: Maybe try different graphics drivers under Software and Updates -> Additional Drivers?

Comment: Experiencing the same problem. just working on a terminal freezes the entire system.

Comment: What is the kernel version?

Comment: I've been experiencing the same freezing problem on two newly installed servers.  Two different computers (completely different hardware including video cards).   22.04.2 5.15.0-73-generic (also happened on 5.15.0-72-generic before upgrading)

Comment: $ inxi -G
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GT218 [GeForce 210]
           Display Server: X.org 1.19.6 driver: nvidia
           tty size: 91x58 Advanced Data: N/A for root

Comment: $ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel 4 Series Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel
  Display: server: No display server data found. Headless machine?
  Message: GL data unavailable for root.