# Ubuntu 22.04.1, got stuck with the option "Continue using a manually installed driver"

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'd be glad if someone could help me out. I'm running 22.04.1 on a notebook with Nvidia GTX1650. I tried changing the Nvidia driver from 510 to 515 in the "Additional Drivers" GUI. The change failed, probably due to temporary internet disconnect, I tried it a couple of more times, it failed again, until I tried to play it safe and switch to the noveau driver. However, at that point I got stuck with the option "Continue using a manually installed driver".
I reviewed this previous string in depth: [Not able to change the Nvidia driver in ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237590/not-able-to-change-the-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu-20-04), but couldn't find an answer applicable to my scenario.

E.g. when I try

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

I get

```
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 513, in <module>
    greet()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 413, in install
    command_install(config)
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 187, in command_install
    UbuntuDrivers.detect.nvidia_desktop_pre_installation_hook(to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UbuntuDrivers/detect.py", line 839, in nvidia_desktop_pre_installation_hook
    with_nvidia_kms = version >= 470
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'version' referenced before assignment
```

If I try

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

I get nearly identical output

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 513, in <module>
    greet()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 432, in autoinstall
    command_install(config)
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 187, in command_install
    UbuntuDrivers.detect.nvidia_desktop_pre_installation_hook(to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UbuntuDrivers/detect.py", line 839, in nvidia_desktop_pre_installation_hook
    with_nvidia_kms = version >= 470
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'version' referenced before assignment
```

And when I try removing all Nvidia packages:

```
sudo dpkg -P $(dpkg -l | grep nvidia-driver | awk '{print $2}')
```

I get

```
dpkg: error: --purge needs at least one package name argument
```

But I can't find out which argument is the correct one.

So to sum up, seems like I'm stuck with the integrated UHD Graphics at the moment, unable to use my Nvidia.
Settings > About:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Aedt.png)

Any ideas on how I can get a valid Nvidia driver installed again?

Answer (score 1):

I connected to a more stable network, then ran:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470
```

This installed the somewhat older 470 driver. Now the *Continue using a manually installed driver* is gone in the Additional Drivers GUI, and the other options are active, not grayed out.

Comment: It worked for me too.. the only difference is that I had to use driver version 390, which is the latest version available for my old nvidia laptop video card NVS 4200M. sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390 Thank you !

Comment: This worked for me too, but after installing 470 I installed 525. For whichever reason, if I try to change driver in the GUI I just get an "X" pop up. However, now I have the latest driver.